# Unable to run the java class from php using PHP-Java Bridge

Tags: java, php, php-java-bridge

I am calling a java class from PHP program using Php-Java Bridge and I am using the Tomcat server.
Where I have created a Jar file of my java program and put it in `C:\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\JavaBridge\WEB-INF\lib` this folder and my small PHP script which call java program resides in `C:\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\test` folder
My jar file name and java class name is same.

File Name: NewFIle.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NewFile {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         File file = new File("E:/myfile");

         if(file.createNewFile())System.out.println("Success!");
         else System.out.println ("Error, file already exists.");
      }
      catch(IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

File Name: test.php

```
<?php 

require_once("java/Java.inc");
// echo java("java.lang.System")->getProperties();

echo java("NewFile");

echo "Hello";
// print_r($data);
?>
```

I am getting an empty output problem to seem where I am calling java program, the java program which I wrote is creating a normal file in a particular file location.

Please Let me know what i am doing wrong any suggestion will be accepted.
I know about PHP exec command but I am not able to execute with PHP-JAVA bridge

Steps screenshots from installation guide and user guide..

[image]

Second Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to include the result of `http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc`? Shouldn't it be just `java/Java.inc` as written on http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/tomcat6.php? Which steps of http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/installation.php have you completed? Please [edit] your question to include the results of each step listed in the installation and PHP guide of PHP-Java bridge.

Comment: Yes sir, I have completed each and every step that listed in the installation, let me edit the question @Progman